# How to add a line to the end of a file which I can access via sudo?

Tags: shell, file-permissions, sudo

I have tried:

```
sudo "some string" >> test.txt
```

But I am getting permission denied warning.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depends on how much access your administrator has given you via sudo.  The simplest answer, assuming that you have permission to do so, is to run "sudo -s" to get a privileged shell and then just do your

```
echo somestring >> test.txt
```

as 'normal'.  If you need to do it automatedly:

```
sudo /bin/sh -c 'echo somestring >> test.txt'
```

The reason that what you have won't work (other than the fact that you left what I assume to be an "echo" command out) is that the file redirection happens in the context of your shell and the sudo only applies to the command you told it to run.

Comment: have you considered `sudo -s` instead of firing up /bin/sh explicitly?

Comment: Yes.  It's the first option I list.

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'some string' >> test.txt"
```

The problem in your original try is that the ">>" is happening in the shell running as you; bash opens the file, not whatever is being run by sudo.  In my version, you're passing the whole command including the redirection to a bash run by sudo.

Comment: have you considered sudo -s instead of firing up /bin/sh explicitly?

Comment: Nerdling: On my systems, "sudo -s" runs the shell you specify, it doesn't really support running complicated multi-argument things like this.

Answer (score 13):

```
% echo "string" | sudo tee -a test.txt
```

Comment: Has the side effect of echoing the string to stdout, but nice and short...

Comment: if you don't want to echo to stdout

    echo "string" | sudo tee test.txt > /dev/null

Comment: the real value of 'tee' is that all the 'work' is done in the context of the normal user and only the output is written with 'sudo' powers. for me thats more important than the shortness and more 'correct' than the other answers, allthough they work of coz.

Comment: It's a good solution.

Comment: +1 This is the best solution because the main part of the command executes with limited privilege, and only the output gets written as root.

Comment: Need to use the -a switch if you don't want to overwrite

Answer (score 0):

You can try [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way:

```
sudo ex +'$put =\"some string\"' -cwq foo.txt
```

It's simple in-place file editing and it's useful in scripts, so you don't have to do any shell piping.

Comment: Isn't `sed` easier here?

Comment: @chicks `sed` is more stream oriented (can only read the file forward), so you'll have to read the whole file. `ex` is editor (predecessor of `vi`), so you can place the cursor at the end and append the text, so it allows more complex things to do.  You still can use `-i` (in-place) in `sed`, but this option is not quite compatible between Linux/Unix and we don't have any pattern to replace here, so I guess it won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of people recommend `tee` for this, but I don't like the side-effect of writing to `stdout`.  An alternative is `cat`:

```
sh some_script.sh | sudo sh -c 'cat >> somefile.txt'
```

If `cat` had an argument like `tee`'s `-a` flag, that would be a little handier:

```
sh some_script.sh | sudo pseudocat -a somefile.txt
```

But unfortunately it doesn't.