# bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, sudo

Why when I run I get the error:

```
$ sudo echo "127.0.0.1 db-local.internal" >> /etc/hosts
bash: /etc/hosts: Permission denied
```

But when I do `sudo su` I can edit this file without any problem.

**UPD**
Because question is closed I add answer here:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'some string' >> test.txt"
```

Link: https://serverfault.com/a/68544/307225

Comment: then you're not in sudoers

Comment: make sure you are in /etc/sudoers and allowed to do more than just 'sudo su'

Comment: you can also try 'sudo -user=root echo "127.0.0.1 db-local.internal" >> /etc/hosts'

Comment: @Rob-d There is no indication that the user does not have `sudo` rights. The problem here occurs because the shell redirect happens in the user's security context, not sudo context. The user themselves doesn't have rights to edit the file /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo 'echo "127.0.0.1 db-local.internal" >> /etc/hosts'
```

The way you written it, you will try to append the output of `sudo` to `/etc/hosts` before the `sudo` becomes active.

Comment: sudo: echo "127.0.0.1 db-local.internal" >> /etc/hosts: command not found

Comment: Another approach might be to use [`tee`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29). i.e. `echo "127.0.0.1 db-local.internal" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts`. This forces the append operation to run in the context of a UID `0` user. See [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/68557/131019) in the linked duplicate question, which also describes this method.

Comment: I have found answer at different topic

Comment: @EugenKonkov was that other solution: `sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo hello >> /etc/hosts`?

Comment: @a.t.: Answer is here: https://serverfault.com/a/68544/307225